# Add "Double-Click to Continue" option with FaceID

Tags: ios, swift, applepay, face-id, lacontext

In my app I use the Apple's FaceID to confirm some actions.

I want to insert an additional step before the FaceID request is presented.
This because the FaceID appears immediately and the user doesn't have the time to read what he's going to confirm.

I saw that Apple use the approach to "Double-Click the Home button" before asking for FaceID.

I've read the Apple's docs but I didn't find any informations about this kind of API. I attached a screenshot with an example of what Apple does in its native apps.

[image: Apple's Double-Click to Continue]

Do you know how to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe apps have the ability to access side button presses.

If you don't want Face ID to immediately appear and authenticate, perhaps add a `UIButton` in-app for the user to tap before the Face ID authentication appears.